# How are the "cache" files generated by PHP Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am new to Symfony, but have experience with other web frameworks eg Ruby on Rails.

I'm trying to modify a web page, and I traced the template to a particular file:
`cache/backend/dev/modules/autoUsers/templates/indexSuccess.php`

If I update this file, the web page is updated.

However, this file is not in the git repository.  And given the top directory is called `cache`, I surmise that this file was generated by Symfony.  So modifying this file directly is probably not the right solution.

I'm trying to understand how the cache file is generated, how I can find the places of the real source files to make the change.  Can someone explain please?

After I make the changes, how can I then regenerate the cache file?
Or is this something handled automatically by Symfony/PHP?

Thanks you.

Comment: You should probably follow the documentation and install the demo app.  I know you want to focus on your changes but there is quite a bit of stuff going on in Symfony 2.  Spending some time to understand the basics will save you a lot more time in the future.   Pay particular attention to  the differences between development and production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you refer to the version 1 of the framework.

The default implementation of the CRUD module is generated in a folder named `cache`. If you want to modify the file (and you don't want to lost your modified version) you must copy it in the module and action folder.

In your case, you must put the file in the specified folder:

```
apps/backend/modules/users/templates/indexSuccess.php
```

More info in the section **Templates Customization**  in the [doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/12?orm=Propel):

> As for the classes, you can also override the original templates. As
>   templates are plain PHP files and not PHP classes, a template can be
>   overridden by creating a template of the same name in the module (for
>   instance in the apps/backend/modules/job/templates/ directory for the
>   job admin module):

Hope this help